# How do i pass a forms "text" input into another variable that is in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

In my Django project, I have to take the input from **forms** and pass it as an argument for a function that is in **views.py**. How do I do it?

My views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from search_engine import query
from .forms import SearchForm


def query_input(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = SearchForm(request.POST)

    else:
        form = SearchForm()
        return render(request, 'search.html', {'form': form})

def search_results(request):
    search_results = query.results(# text input from forms)
    a = "<br /><br />".join(word for word in search_results)
    return HttpResponse(a)
```

My forms.py code

```
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    your_query = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: By writing code in the view... If you want a specific answer, I propose that you share a (sample) view, together with input and expected output. Right now this is very broad, and can probably not answered in a good way.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem, I have edited my question can you please check it now

Answer (score 1):

After you checked that the request method is a POST you can validate the form and then access its attributes like this

In views.py:

```
if request.method = "POST":
    form = SearchForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        search_text = form.cleaned_data['search_text']
        # code from search_results function to return HTTP Response
```

Check out the documentation on forms and view [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#the-view) for more information.